# Как сделать фигуры в background только c помощью css

Tags: css, svg

[image: menu]

Пробовал сделать с помощью

```
transform: perspective(7px) rotateX(2deg);
```

и вроде получилось с первым пунктом но вот остальные не получается подогнать пожалуйста помогите и дайте как можно развернутый ответ.

Comment: может тут надо svg?

Comment: А можно поинтересоваться, чем не устроило просто поставить картинку на фон?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ подскажи как это сделать как сделать фигуру в svg и как потом ее использовать в background?

Comment: @МихаилВолков background не понадобится

Comment: @Михаил Волков загрузите код с меню сюда, я сделаю вашим методом и объясню как.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант с использованием `clip-path`

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: orange;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menu>li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75));
}

.menu>li+li {
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.menu>li:nth-of-type(1) {
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu>li:nth-of-type(3) {
  z-index: 2;
}

.menu>li:nth-of-type(4) {
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu>li>a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #fff;
  width: 120px;
  height: 70px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 85% 100%, 15% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 85% 100%, 15% 100%);
}

.menu>li:nth-of-type(2)>a,
.menu>li:nth-of-type(4)>a {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 80% 100%, 15% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 80% 100%, 15% 100%);
}

.menu>li:nth-of-type(3)>a {
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu>li:nth-of-type(3)>a,
.menu>li:nth-of-type(6)>a {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 90% 100%, 10% 90%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 90% 100%, 10% 90%);
}

.menu>li:hover {
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Очень круто! Жалко, что вы стали реже отвечать,  чем это было раньше

Answer (score 3):

Вот собрал на `svg`+`d3.js` формы блоков генерируются более менее случайным образом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
let d = "Alle tekst komt van schrijvers die".split(" ");
let left = 0;
let groups = d3.select('svg')
  .selectAll('g')
  .data(d) 
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', d => {
    let t = `translate(${20+left*10}, -1)`;
    left += d.length+1;
    return t;
  })
  .on('click', function() {
    d3.selectAll('g').classed('active', false);
    d3.select(this).raise().classed('active', true);
  });
     

  groups.append('path')
        .attr('d', d => `
          M${-10-rnd(10)},0 
          L${rnd(-10)},${20+rnd(10)}
          L${d.length*10},${20+rnd(10)}
          L${d.length*10+rnd(10)},0 Z
        `)
    

function rnd(base){
  return Math.random()*base;
}

groups.append('text')  
      .text(d => d)
      .attr('y', 15)
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  background-color: rgba(255,222,0,1);
}

path {
  stroke: black;
  fill: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  filter:url(#shadow);
  transition: 200ms;
}

path:hover {
  fill: lightgray;
}

text {
  pointer-events:none;
  font-family: monospace;
  cursor: pointer;
}

g.active path {
  fill: wheat;
}

g.active path:hover {
  fill: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg viewbox="0 0 500 150">
  
  <defs>
    <filter id="shadow" height="130%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"/>
      <feOffset dx="2" dy="2" result="offsetblur"/> 
      <feComponentTransfer>
        <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.5"/>
      </feComponentTransfer>
      <feMerge> 
        <feMergeNode/> 
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>

</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте ntc-child. Например если вы используйте `transform: perspective(7px) rotateX(2deg);` для div с классом menu, то код будет таким:

```
div.menu:nth-child(1) {
transform: perspective(7px) rotateX(2deg);
}
```

Далее вам надо, чтобы код для остальных отличался, тогда далее:

```
div.menu:nth-child(2) {
    transform: ...
    }
div.menu:nth-child(3) {
    transform: ...
    }
```

и т.д.

Comment: Нормально... в итоге стали использовать ntc решение. Но, ответ присудили другому.

Comment: Уважаемый, на ruSO приветствуются либо полностью рабочие варианты, либо развёрнутые ответы. Скорость ответа, в большинстве случаев, не является гарантией того, что ваш ответ признают лучшим. Как правило, "скоростные" ответы порождают ещё больше вопросов, тем самым нивелируя ту самую скорость. Если же ответ действительно хорош, то через некоторое время, его оценят. Для погони за репутацией, этот сайт не подходит, ибо в первую очередь, призван помочь людям (причём, бескорыстно). К тому же, "разжевав" ответ кому-то, Вы закрепляете собственные знания. Удачи ;-)

Comment: @UModeL Репутация тут ничего особого не значит.